# Creating/Populating New DataFrame columns based on multiple if/elif conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains two sources of addresses, the ship to and bill to address. I am looking to apply conditional logic to merge these addresses into one usable address.

```
     CID          Ship Line 1  Ship Postcode           Bill Line 1  \
0  CUST1                  NaN          10001  Cust1 Address Line 1   
1  CUST2                  NaN          39458  Cust2 Address Line 1   
2  CUST3  Cust3 Addres Line 1          20002                   NaN   

   Bill Postcode  
0        10001.0  
1            NaN  
2        20004.0
```

Pseudocode of what I am trying to achieve:

> If the Ship-to Postcode is equal to the Bill-to Postcode, then enrich the address line 1 from either the Ship and Bill sections (i.e. assume they are the same, take whichever is populated).
>
> If the ship to postcode is different to the bill to postcode, then use only Ship to address line 1. Vice versa.

I have tried the following as a test:

```
def addresschoice(row):
    if row['Ship Postcode'] ==  row['Bill Postcode']:
        #identify which address will be chosen
        return row['Address Selected'] = 'Ship To'

    else:
        return row['Address Selected'] = 'Bill To'

customers_staging.apply(addresschoice, axis=1)
```

but im struggling to progress.

Answer (score 0):

**Example Code**

I will define your input as `df`.

```
import pandas as pd
nan = float('nan')
data1 = {'CID': ['CUST1', 'CUST2', 'CUST3'], 
         'Ship Line 1': [nan, nan, 'Cust3 Addres Line 1'],
         'Ship Postcode': [10001, 39458, 20002],
         'Bill Line 1': ['Cust1 Address Line 1', 'Cust2 Address Line 1', nan],
         'Bill Postcode': [10001, nan, 20004],
         'Address Selected': ['Ship To', 'Bill To', 'Bill To']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

**Code**

In your attempt, using "=" in return is grammatically incorrect, but since your approach is not correct anyway, there is no need to correct it.

use `np.where`

```
import numpy as np
cond = df['Ship Postcode'] == df['Bill Postcode']
df['Address Selected'] = np.where(cond, 'Ship To', 'Bill To')
```

df

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am interested in setting the value of df['Selected Address Line 1'] equal to which ever column isn't blank. How could i do this also?

Comment: @andrew1990 need clear explanation.